# Замена последней строки

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Может быть есть у кого-то набросок замены последней строки в файле - в цикле. Т.е. что-то вроде

```
While(True) 
{ 
    заменяем последнюю строку; 
    if($s == false) exit(''); 
}
```

Comment: зачем цикл ?

Comment: Это как пример использования.
Для того чтобы выводить последние данные в файл, допустим счетчик циклов, чтобы не было такой каши, как "1,2,3,4" а эта цифра всегда подменялась последней. Вот такая идея.

Comment: @xenoll Кнопка 101010 в редакторе форматирует код.

Answer (score 1):

Менять последнюю строку... На что?

Заводите буферную переменную. Читаете туда первую строку. Затем цикл по строкам (от второй до конца). В цикле выводите буферную переменную и заносите туда следующую строку. После выхода из цикла в буфере у вас последняя строка. Заменяете её на что нужно и выводите. Если файл пустой, обламываетесь на первом чтении.